# Using Ref/Out as parameters in recursive function

Tags: c#, recursion, data-structures, linked-list, recursive-datastructures

I am learning datastructures and algorithms.

While solving one of the problem, I have got misunderstanding/confusion with the out/ref parameter in the recursion function call.

So, I want to clarify whether, my understanding is right.

Code:-

```
class Node
{
    public int data;
    public Node Next;
}

void reverse(Node pre, Node current, out Node newRoot)
{
    if (current.Next != null)
    {
        reverse(current, current.Next, out newRoot);
        current.Next = pre;
    }
    else
    {
        newRoot = current; // 5
        current.Next = pre;
    }
}

Node root1 = new Node()
{
    data = 1
};

Node root2 = new Node()
{
    data = 2
};
```

Etc.

```
root1.Next = root2;
root2.Next = root3;
```

Etc.

Calling Place:-

```
Node newRoot = null;
reverse(null, root1, out newRoot);
```

InPut : 1->2->3->4->5

OutPut: 5->4->3->2->1

Purpose:-

The reverse function, will reverse the single linked list recursivly and return the new updated root pointer (which is newRoot).

So, lets consider the following case:-

The function is recursivly called and reached the end of the linked list.

So, "Current" Parameters value will be 5 and the "Pre" param value will be 4.

so the "if" case will fail (since there is no "next" data for it)... So it will come to the else case and assign the "newRoot" parameter (as 5)

and the current call ends and goes to the previous call stack.

When newRoot param is not passed as "out" parameter, when the last function call ends (as described above) the current value of the newRoot will be lost.

My understanding:- 
1. When the parameter is not a ref/out parameter, then for each call, each parameter will be newly created and pushed into stack 
2. When it is a ref/out parameter, then only single copy is created/available irrespective of the depth of the call and the same will be used entirely. 
3. So, this ref/out parameter can be considered as a global/static variable

Could some one help me, in understanding this one correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (2) is incorrect. ref references another variable. It can be any variable at all and each recursive call frame can receive a different reference.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure of what you try to understand, but there is a fundamental difference between an out parameter and a static variable: context.

A static variable is available in the whole context of its visibility attribute: public, internal protected or private.

The out variable is only available in the context of your recursive function.

In other words, using a static variable instead of an out parameter might lead to error in your case, because someone might change the value of the variable during a call to the recursive function.